# Different math format in section title and TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents

If I use \boldsymbol in my subsection title, then the symbol that matches the font in the text but it does not match the font in the TOC.  I have two examples in this picture, one where the font agrees in the text and one where the font agrees in the TOC.  How can I get the bold math symbol in the subsection title in the text but the non-bold math symbol in the TOC?

[image: O]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
$~$\newline\newline
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Subsection with no math symbols}
\subsection{Subsection with $\boldsymbol{\hat \Upsilon}$}
\subsection{Subsection with $\hat \Upsilon$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\subsection[Subsection with $\hat \Upsilon$]{Subsection with $\boldsymbol{\hat \Upsilon}$}` is what you are asking for.

Comment: Are you sure you want to make the symbol bold in the section title? Mathematical symbols usually have a meaning, and making them bold might suggest another meaning.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Best answer I ever got on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @hodopsmith Thank you! Actually, I also find David Carlisle's answer very inspiring.

Comment: no sorry, the answer you accepted is structurally wrong, it's misusing `\boldsymbol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional argument in `\section` or `\subsection` to set the name in ToC.
For example

```
\section[<Name in ToC>]{<Name in Section Title>}
```

So consider the MWE as

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
$~$\newline\newline
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Subsection with no math symbols}
\subsection[Subsection with $\hat \Upsilon$]{Subsection with $\boldsymbol{\hat \Upsilon}$}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `\boldsymbol`if the bold has mathematical meaning, for example vectors, and in such a case you would want that meaning to be preserved in the table of contents.

Using bold math in section headings to match the bold text font is a design choice so should be part of the heading specification, you had already loaded `titlesec`  so you could use it to specify bold text and math headings.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\boldmath}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\boldmath}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% no!!!!!!$~$\newline\newline Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--9% 
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Subsection with no math symbols}
\subsection{Subsection with $\boldsymbol{\hat \Upsilon}$}
\subsection{Subsection with $\hat \Upsilon$}
\end{document}
```